# Proper Formatting for Simple Tables in LaTeX

Tags: tables

I have a table as below that doesn't format properly through pdfLaTeX.  Specifically, the vertical lines for each row don't extend all the way down to create a complete box.  Is there a better way to do this? The code is below.

```
  \begin{table}[!ht]
    \fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont
    \caption{Caption.}\label{label}
    \center{
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    &a&b&c&d\\
    \hline
    &e&f&g&h\\
    \hline
    &i&j&k&l\\
    \end{tabular}
    }
    \end{table}
```

Comment: You are declaring 4 columns but inserting 5 in the table. Remove the first & at the begin of every row and it will work. For closing the "box" you also need another `\hline` at the end of the last row.

Comment: @dcmst Thanks, I completely overlooked that!

Comment: In addition to fixing the issues identified by @dcmst, you should also consider using far fewer vertical and horizontal lines to begin with. Start with the vertical lines: Is there any loss of meaning if they're all deleted? If not, delete them, and let the table's cells "breathe" a bit. Next, can you make do with fewer horizontal lines? In all likelihood, the answer is yes. In general, let yourself be guided by the mantra "less is more".

Comment: And consider using `booktabs` (and reading its documentation on table design).

Comment: And as a side note, welcome to TeX.SE! :)

Comment: `\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont` would set 12pt font on a 12pt baseline (ie no space between the lines and produce horrible uneven output) you should almost neve need `\fontsize` within a document. use `\normalsize` or `\large` or whatever.

Comment: `\center` is the internal form of `\begin{center}` it should not be used as a command (and does not take a `{}` argument, use `\centering` (with no `{..}`)

Answer (score 4):

Summarizing the comments made above, you should consider using the following code to create the sample 3 by 4 table:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[!ht]
    \large        %% not "\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont"
    \caption{Caption.}\label{label}
    \centering    %% not "\center{...}"
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    a&b&c&d\\     %% no "&" at start of row
    \hline
    e&f&g&h\\
    \hline
    i&j&k&l\\
    \hline        %% extra \hline at bottom of table
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I trust you are working your way toward creating somewhat more exciting tables than the one above. When you do, you should aim for an open, "breathing" look -- rather than one dominated by lots and lots of little "jail cells" that imprison the data. A great place to start this quest is the [user guide](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) of the `booktabs` package; it provides a wonderful guide to open, interesting, and clean-looking tables.

Comment: In addition to the `booktabs` user guide: http://i.imgur.com/ZY8dKpA.gif An excellent walkthrough and example.